# How to add attachment to an existing JIRA Issue using rest-client API

Tags: java, attachment, jira-rest-java-api

I could create a jira issue using the rest client API, but i wasn't able to attach the screeshot/attachment to the exsiting `JIRA` issue. Would be really helpful if anyone could provide a solution which would be really appreciated.

I just wrote the below code snippet for attaching a jpeg file to the existing `JIRA Issue`. But then i experienced "Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpConnectionManager"`

Code Snippet :-

private static String addAttachment(String attachmentfilepath) throws URISyntaxException, FileNotFoundException{

```
    final java.net.URI jiraServerUri = new java.net.URI("https://oliveits.atlassian.net");
    FileInputStream fileStreamPath = new FileInputStream(attachmentfilenamepath);
    JerseyJiraRestClientFactory factory = new JerseyJiraRestClientFactory();
    NullProgressMonitor pm = new NullProgressMonitor();
    System.out.println("Server Url  :"+jiraServerUri);
    JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri,"mobileqa","MobileQA1234");
    Issue issue1 = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue(newKey, pm);
    final java.net.URI AttachmentUri = new java.net.URI(jiraServerUri+"/rest/api/2/issue/"+newKey+"/attachments");
    System.out.println("URI    :"+issue1.getAttachmentsUri());
    //restClient.getIssueClient().addAttachment(pm,issue1.getAttachmentsUri(), fileStreamPath , imageName);
    restClient.getIssueClient().addAttachment(pm, AttachmentUri, fileStreamPath, imageName);
    return attachmentfilepath;
}
```

Exception:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpConnectionManager
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyJiraRestClientFactory.create(JerseyJiraRestClientFactory.java:34)
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyJiraRestClientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(JerseyJiraRestClientFactory.java:39)
at com.jtricks.JTricksRESTClient.addAttachment(JTricksRESTClient.java:157)
at com.jtricks.JTricksRESTClient.main(JTricksRESTClient.java:101)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnectionManager
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 4 more
```

Just added the missing jar files to the classpath. But I'm getting an exception as mentioned below.

Exception Msg-1: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java class com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart, and Java type class com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart, and MIME media type multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary_1_18541827_1358346116249 was not found

Exception Msg-2: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java class com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart, and Java type class com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart, and MIME media type multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary_1_18541827_1358346116249 was not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue comes from inability to find `org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnectionManager` class. Look for `commons-httpclient` JAR in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I just added the commons-httpclient jar file to the classpath. Still it doesn't work, but then i got a different exception

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/client/apache/config/ApacheHttpClientConfig

Comment: Now you're missing jersey-apache-client: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-apache-client/1.1.3-ea

Comment: could you remove this your comment and post it as the update to problem description?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```java
String issueKey = "your-issue";

JiraRestClient restClient 
  = AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory()
                .createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(
                        getJiraUri(), 
                        username,
                        password);

Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue(issueKey).claim();
restClient.getIssueClient().addAttachments(issue.getAttachmentsUri(), file).claim();
restClient.close();
```

in the pom.xml

```xml
    <properties>
        <jira-rest-java-client-core.version>5.2.4</jira-rest-java-client-core.version>
        <atlassian.fugue.version>5.0.0</atlassian.fugue.version>
    </properties>
...

    <dependencies>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jira-rest-java-client-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jira-rest-java-client-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.atlassian.fugue</groupId>
            <artifactId>fugue</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.fugue.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```